# play Next song using Soundcloud and wordpress ifram

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, soundcloud

i have a WordPress site made up of posts of individual Soundcloud tracks , and i need the next track (in the next post) to play when the previous track has finished because my home page made with latest posts.

i tryed a lot of js functions but still cant make it works .

here is my website : [invisibleradio](http://invisibleradio.com/)

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution for the poeple who face the same issue :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var next_widget ;
var iframes =[];
var its_the_last = false;

(function() {
iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
//iframe.src = 'http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/43315398&auto_play=true';
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    //var widget_+i = SC.Widget(iframes[i]);
    window['widget_'+i] = SC.Widget(iframes[i]);
    var widget = SC.Widget(iframes[i]);



    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function(eventData) {
      //var j = this.name;
     // next_widget = window['widget_'+i];
     var widget_i = this;
     for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
       if(SC.Widget(iframes[i]) === widget_i){
        if (i+1 >= iframes.length) {
          its_the_last = true;
        }else{
          next_widget = SC.Widget(iframes[i+1]);
        }


       }else{

        console.log('error');
       }
     };
    });

    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function(eventData) {
      if (its_the_last == false) {
        next_widget.play();
      }

    });


};

}());
</script>
```